# Are django Template tags part of View in MVC architecture?

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-templates

according to definition of MVC architecture and responsibilities of View Layer can we say Django template tags are part of View Layer ?
if it is true so we should not access our data model inside of template tags and so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450289/django-custom-tag-how) violate MVC architecture rules ?

Answer (score 0):

In a sense I would say yes.

Since your code logic (model) and your view (template) logic are separate it would be very similar, you can debate that URL.py would act as your controller ( the router )

I would check out the below to get a better understanding it's much more detailed.

Similar Question and Explanation.

[Django vs. Model View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6621653/django-vs-model-view-controller)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Django FAQ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names):

> In our interpretation of MVC, the “view” describes the data that gets presented to the user. It’s not necessarily how the data looks, but which data is presented. The view describes which data you see, not how you see it. It’s a subtle distinction.

However, Django is more often described as a 'Model-View-Template' architecture (and does so itself in the FAQ). Where the View determines *which* data is presented, the template determines *how* the data is presented. From this point of view the template is *not* part of the view.

For this specific question/answer, I would say this does not belong in a template tag. It does not handle any presentation logic, but rather it handles the retrieval of data. This is generally better done in the view or, if the data should be available side-wide, in a context processor.

Answer (score 0):

A view generally renders data. To do so it needs access to data. Yes, you want to keep your view and data decoupled. But you have to be reasonable about it too. It's a trade off. If you copy the data into another date structure, that is something intermediate between the model and the view, you may make your application slower.
The alternative is to not use django templates and simply send data back from django via a rest api. But if you are using django templates then the answer you mentioned is reasonable.